# @JeromeLouvel better understanding of Restlet

Tags: restlet-2.0

Is there a place or a way to better get a full understanding of how to leverage the Restlet API? Specifically....

What is the difference between stating a Server such as:

```
new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8800, SimplerTest.class).start();
```

And this way:

```
Server helloServer = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8111, MySeverStuff.class);
        helloServer.start();
// where MyServerStuff has a plain @Get that returns a string
```

And this way:

```
Server nServer = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8110);
        nServer.setNext(new MyTestServer()); // where MyTestServer is the class referenced
        nServer.start();
```

And finally this:

```
Component component = new Component(); //creating a new component
                component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8200);
                component.getDefaultHost().attach(new SimpleApplication());
                component.start();
```

So I guess I seem to lack the true understanding of how certain methods are being leveraged. Now the book does not really and truly or fully explain such nuances, nor does it really enlighten about how to leverage:
Directory, Routing, Context, Application, Filter, Message Headers, etc.

Would love to see a more indepth demo and code.
Any idea where one can find such resources ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your interest.

We have been working on a more comprehensive Restlet tutorial recently that we are about to publish on Restlet.com For now, you can read it on GitHub:
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-tutorial

Usage of Restlet API really depends on what you want to do with RF and how you want to deploy your Restlet code. Can you clarify?